# Summary Statistics tool for Mean Z values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-statistics, arcgis-10.2

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2
The summary statistics tool is not functioning in the way that I want. I made an elevation layer that is a DSM, and then in my buildings layer I determined the height for buildings by creating a random points sample. Now that all the random points in each building have an elevation, or z-value, I want to get the mean for each building. I used the summary statistics tool, but it calculates a summarized mean for all 482100 buildings combined. I want the z-mean summarized for each individual building, this is possible because the buildings all have an unique ID number. See Attached Photo,

[image: Z mean value operation]

Answer (score 2):

I think you should consider creating a DEM, and then use [zonal statistics as table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000w8000000.htm) to generate statistics. You can use a unique field in your building layer to base your statistics on.  You then join the table back to your building layer by your unique field.

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: I performed a zonal statistics table operation by inserting my building point elevations as an input raster and the normalized Digital Surface Model (nDSM) as the input value raster, I then set the statistics type as mean. This gave my a zonal statistics mean field. I hope the nDSM is the correct surface to insert. Is the tabular field that resulted a mean calculation of the Z field within Buildings height layer attribute table?

Comment: If your nDSM represents elevation, I would use your building polygon as the 'input raster/feature zone data'.  Set the 'Zone filed' to a unique id in the building layer.  Set 'Input value raster' to the nDSM, specify an output, and select MEAN as stat type.  Your table should result in a mean value for each building unique id.